# operator new already has a body

Tags: c++, operators, new-operator

I am trying to implement operator new with parameter as global. There is no problem if new without args is overloaded, but I get followings errors when trying to compile

```
inline void* operator new(size_t, void* p) {
    //...
    return p;
}
```

> c:\bjarne_exercise_6.cpp(14): error C2084: function 'void *operator new(size_t,void *) throw()' already has a body
>             c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\new(55) : see previous definition of 'new'
>
> c:\bjarne_exercise_6.cpp(40): error C2264: 'operator new' : error in function definition or declaration; function not called

I have just solved this, you have to declare this before you #include stdafx.h
No, not true. It compile well but still not this function is called but the version from new header file. It is so, because placement new(with 2 params) is already defined in new header. The ordinary new (with just 1, size_t parameter) is only declared there, so you can still overload it. So if you want special new with more than 1 parameter the solution suggested by @trion below is appropriate.

Comment: Do you have a minimal/complete program that shows this problem? Something small with your new and just a `main` that maybe tries to use it?

Comment: Did you `#include <new>`? And don't `inline`.

Comment: I have just solved this, you have to declare this before you #include stdafx.h

Comment: but still it is not clear to me why operator new(size_t) has compiled well even then, but not new(size_t,void*p). only the latter gives errors, both are from <new> and are there declared

Comment: @cf16: `void* operator new(size_t);` is one of a very few special functions called "replaceable", meaning you can define it even though the implementation otherwise would, and if you do your definition will be used instead.

Comment: and the same with void* operator new(size_t, void *), isn't it?

Comment: no, ok, now I understand, as explained in my edit to original post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C++ standard defines a placement `operator new` taking an additional `void*` in the header file `<new>`.
Its implementation is similar to this:

```
void* operator new(size_t, void* m)
{
    return m;
}
```

It's commonly used to instantiate objects on already allocated memory, e.g. by STL containers which separate allocation from instantiation. So if you include any standard header depending on `<new>`, the placement new will already be defined.

If you want to create your own version of `operator new` with different semantics, you can use a dummy parameter to disambiguate the situation:

```
struct my_new_dummy {} dummy;
void* operator new(size_t, my_new_dummy, void* m);

//...

int mem;
int* ptr = new(dummy, &mem) int;
```

**Edit:** The reason why you can redefine the ordinary `operator new` but not placement new, is that the former is by default defined by the compiler and can be overridden manually, whereas placement new is defined in a header, therefore causing a conflict with your re-definition.

Comment: yes, this is some solution but the question remains: why no problem with operator new(size_t): it has compiled well, but not new(size_t,void*p). only the latter gives errors

Comment: Declared, not defined. That's a difference.

Comment: yes it is true. so the placement new (with 2 parameters) is defined in new header and thus "has a body" error, but beacuse new (with just 1, size_t parameter) is only declared in new header you can overload it. right?

Comment: Right. The declaration in `<new>` matches your own implementation of new(size_t), and like @aschepler said in a comment to the original post, new(size_t) will only be defined by the compiler if you don't provide an implementation yourself.

Comment: how this is achieved? I guess there is something #defined if I have written my own new?

Comment: you should perhaps change "The reason why you can redefine the ordinary operator new but not placement new, is that the former is by default defined by the compiler and can be overridden manually" to "the former is by default declared" it's not defined

Comment: probably worth mentioning is that a matching delete needs to be provided for the overridden new op with a dummy injection

Answer (score 5):

This placement form of `operator new` (as the Standard calls it) is already defined in a C++ program in the global namespace, you cannot provide a definition there yourself. Unlike other global `operator new`s, this one is not replaceable.

Comment: it is example from Bjarne book "C++ prog. lang", page 255

Comment: ok, it seems like he just mentioned it as an example, just to show how it can be done, because he said also that "It is defined in the standard header new"

Answer (score 3):

1) You have the compile error because global level placement new operator **cannot** be replaced ! See c++ 11 standards(in previous standards as well).

> ```
> 18.6.1.3 Placement forms [new.delete.placement]
> 1 These functions are reserved, a C++ program may not define functions that
> ```
>
> displace the versions in the
>       Standard C++ library (17.6.4). The provisions of (3.7.4) do not apply to these reserved placement forms of
>       operator new and operator delete.
>       void* operator new(std::size_t size, void* ptr) noexcept;

So basically you can replace the other global new operator(see below), but **NOT** the placement form as the standards forbid it !

```
void* operator new (std::size_t size) throw (std::bad_alloc)
```

2) On the other hand, you can write your own class level new operators including the placement new one inside your class, that's ok:

```
class Test
{
public:

    void* operator new (std::size_t size) throw (std::bad_alloc) {
        return malloc(size);
    }

    void* operator new (std::size_t size, const std::nothrow_t& nothrow_constant) throw() {
        return malloc(size);
    }

    void* operator new (std::size_t size, void* ptr) throw() {
        return malloc(size);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

yes. This placement form of `operator new` is already defined in a global namespace, so that you cannot provide a definition there yourself. This is not replaceable.